# Changing orientation while editing comment crashes app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

The app crashes on changing the screen orientation while editing a comment.

Version: 0.1.63

Comment: That's why you shouldn't comment while driving.

Comment: @Manishearth I was lying in bed but yeah, that too :P

Comment: Trying to reproduce in 0.1.68. EDIT: just rotating the phone doesn't cause the app to crash in 0.1.68, but rotating then hitting 'post' will cause the app to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in version 0.1.72 coming out later tonight (in a 2-3 hours), thanks!

BTW: This was actually just the first symptom we caught of a really big bug, super happy you folks saw it since I hadn't.

Comment: I hope not [that big of a bug](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Computer_bug.svg)? :-P